# apply_authorization_limits is not called

Tags: django, api, tastypie

I try to get details about my authenticated user in my Django app.

For that I created a new resource :

```
class MyUserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = ReaderUser.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'me'
        list_allowed_methods = []
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get']
        authorization = Authorization()
        authentication = SessionAuthentication()
        excludes = ('password', 'id', 'is_active', 'is_admin', 'last_login')

    def apply_authorization_limits(self, request, object_list):
        print request.user
        return object_list.filter(pk=request.user.pk)

    def prepend_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/$" % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('dispatch_detail'), name="api_dispatch_detail"),
        ]
```

When I call my API using `/api/me/?format=json`
I got the following : `More than one resource is found at this URI.`

I have also tried without the prepend_urls.
What I don't understand is that the `print` statement is never executed in the method `apply_authorization_limits`

Any hints about what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found two ways to fix my issue:

The first one is two create my own authorization.

In my case, the following:

```
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization

class SimpleReaderAuthorization(Authorization):
    def read_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        return object_list.filter(email=bundle.request.user.email)
```

And I just need to update my resource:

```
class MyUserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = ReaderUser.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'me'
        list_allowed_methods = ['get']
        authorization = SimpleReaderAuthorization()
        authentication = SessionAuthentication()
        excludes = ('password', 'id', 'is_active', 'is_admin', 'last_login')
```

Another simple way is to do the following, as indicated in the [documentation](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#per-request-alterations-to-the-queryset).

```
def get_object_list(self, request): 
        return super(YourResource, self).get_object_list(request).filter(pk=request.user.pk)
```

Conclusion: I chose the second one as it is cleaner, and simple.

Comment: About the second solution, I'd rather go with:

`def get_object(self, request):
     return super(YourResource,self).get_object(pk=request.user.pk)`

This way, you get 1 object instead of a list (that will always contain 1 object), and you respect the REST architecture, requesting http://blabla/me/12 where 12 is the current user.

The con's is that when requesting http://blabla/me/13 (and you are 12), it returns a 404 HTTP code.

Comment: @DavidW.Thanks for your advice. You are right, I should go back to this and see if your solution makes sense.

Comment: @DavidD. the read_list operation is used on returning lists of some resource. To filter individual itens you can use read_detail to return Unauthorized instead of 404 to not permitted resources.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation doesn't show but apply_authorization_limits is set as deprecated.
Not only deprecated, it was ripped from resource life-cycle on Feb 2013 by [this commit](https://github.com/django-tastypie/django-tastypie/commit/d850758b088761a00f60a474f5b2d683dc1ec3c0). That's why it's not called anymore.

The updated documentation at the time is [here](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/v0.9.14/authorization.html) and didn't changed much since then.

Check your tastypie version as 'read_list' is recommended by the [updated documentation](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/stable/authorization.html).

```
def read_list(self, object_list, bundle):
    """
    Returns a list of all the objects a user is allowed to read.

    Should return an empty list if none are allowed.

    Returns the entire list by default.
    """
    return object_list
```

Your code changed would look like this:

```
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization
from tastypie.exceptions import Unauthorized


class MyAuthorization(Authorization):
    def read_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        print request.user
        return object_list.filter(pk=bundle.request.user.pk)


class MyUserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = ReaderUser.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'me'
        list_allowed_methods = []
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get']
        authorization = MyAuthorization()
        authentication = SessionAuthentication()
        excludes = ('password', 'id', 'is_active', 'is_admin', 'last_login')

    def prepend_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/$" % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('dispatch_detail'), name="api_dispatch_detail"),
        ]
```

Or, you can use a resource level Authorization (much simpler in your case):

```
class MyUserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = ReaderUser.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'me'
        list_allowed_methods = []
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get']
        authentication = SessionAuthentication()
        excludes = ('password', 'id', 'is_active', 'is_admin', 'last_login')

    def authorized_read_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        print request.user
        return object_list.filter(pk=bundle.request.user.pk)

    def prepend_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/$" % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('dispatch_detail'), name="api_dispatch_detail"),
        ]
```

Note that there is no need of 'authorization' meta in this case.

Use of 'authorization' meta is good if you have a common and generic way to apply permissions on different resources that share the same authorization class.